# Live refresh and some notifications are broken

Tags: bug, notifications, live-refresh, web-sockets

It seems that since today most of the notifications are broken. With notifications I mean:

- Updated score on questions / answers;
- Live refresh on edited questions / answers;
- Live refresh on comments;
- Updates on own reputation in top bar;
- Notifications in top bar.

Can this be fixed please?

Reproduced on:

- Chrome on Windows (42.0.2311.135)
- Internet Explorer 11 (11.0.9600.17728)
- Firefox 37 on Windows

Comment: [status-norepro]

Comment: @Mooseman do you see the auto-downvote when you flag something as spam?

Comment: Mostly repro'd on Firefox. I see notifications for *new* questions and answers, as well as rep notifications, but not any of the rest.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yup. Network wide.

Comment: The two comments from the two guys above didn't come through. I think about 50% falls off.

Comment: no-repro in IE11 (yeah, finally something that works on IE11)!

Comment: @rene: Sorry, broken here on IE11.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: What version? Might be useful to add that to the post.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: Fx/Win 37.

Comment: OK, it might be broken on MSO/SO...

Comment: You mean live refresh, which is indeed done via web sockets. Notifications are still being sent, you just have to reload in order to see them. And yes, same here for a while - was too lazy to report. :)

Comment: Wait... unless you mean you don't get notifications at all, even after reloading? If so, sorry and please roll back.

Comment: I do get notifications, but not always. And the live updates are broken too.

Comment: We're taking a look now.

Comment: @NickCraver This is not merely a Windows problem nor a Chrome problem. It happens with Safari on a Mac, too. And it didn’t use to.

Comment: @tchrist don't think it's related to browser - more like something is borked on the server side, eating up some notifications.

Comment: We're still at a loss to reproduce this, and haven't seen any significant CPU drop from WSS connections - can anyone reproduce this reliably?

Comment: @Nick the most frequent I see this is when flag as spam. It doesn't show the auto -1.

Comment: @PatrickHofman can you confirm when this started happening? We're still unable to reproduce anything out of place here.

Comment: This morning when I first got to the site using desktop.

Comment: @Nick when having multiple tabs open some update and some don't. Then the one browser updates and the other not... Strange.

Comment: I sometimes don't get the dynamic "show x more comments", even though the comments do show when I reload the page. Real-time rep changes also don't show in the top bar, but they do show when I reload. Strange..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue any more. Apparently Geoff and Nick (they contacted me via mail), fixed the issue while I was asleep. (Posting this so Geoff and Nick can confirm this when I am asleep again)

I can confirm these live updates / notifications do work now:

- Updated question coming through (tested with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30117761/2));
- Auto down-vote on spam / offensive post visible immediately (tested [here](https://superuser.com/a/912210/302087) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/912208/172747));
- Live update on new comments;
- Update on score of questions and answers.